# How to use Pandoc with double-byte characters?

Tags: pdf, fonts, markdown, pandoc

I am trying to convert a Markdown document to PDF. The following works using `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf`:

```
# Test

Testing
```

But this

```
# Test

日本語
```

gives me an error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char 日 (U+65E5)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.62 日

Try running pandoc with --latex-engine=xelatex.
pandoc: Error producing PDF
```

Using `--latex-engine=xelatex` doesn't seem to help. I am using pandoc 1.19.2.1 on Mac OS X.

Using the package markdown-pdf (https://atom.io/packages/markdown-pdf) in Atom also works, but I need to use Pandoc for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are not so much the double-byte characters, it's more that you need to tell Pandoc it should tell LaTeX to use a CJK font.

For me, the current Pandoc version 2.5 on macOS works:

1. You need to use `--pdf-engine=lualatex` or `xelatex` now (no more `--latex-engine`).
2. You need to have installed the *`'xecjk'`* package in your LaTeX installation.
3. You need to add `-V CJKmainfont=...` to your command line.
4. You need to have an appropriate font installed on your system, f.e. *"STSong"*.

So here goes:

```
pandoc                    \
  --pdf-engine=lualatex   \
  -V CJKmainfont="STSong" \
  -o out.pdf              \
   test.md
```